# db2 stored procedure. locking / releasing table

Tags: db2

I use a stored procedure to read/update/return certain fields in a journaled as400 table. 
I want to lock the table first and then release it after the record is updated. I 
tried tons of stuff, but releasing table is a problem. SP defines and opens cursor, 
selects record into variables and updates the record. I tried 'begin atomic', then 
lock table in exclusive mode and then when it's over, it doesn't release.
Is there any statement i missing or do i need to compile it with certain parameters?
I use a simple create procedure statement in AS400 navigator's sql panel to compile it.
Will very appreciate some help with example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The locks will not be released until a COMMIT or ROLLBACK is issued, either within the procedure itself, or from the application that called the procedure.